# Updating a LOB/BLOB value on a HSQLDB with Hibernate produces a data exception

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, hsqldb

Having a strange behaviour with my update code:

**Entity:**

```
@Entity
public class Data {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private long id;

   @Lob
   private byte[] data;

   //Getters and Setters...
}
```

**Spring Data Repository:**

```
@Repository
public interface DataRepository extends JpaRepository<Data, Long> {}
```

**Test Configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"de.ehscheidt.bugs.data"})
public class TestConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("data");
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"de.ehscheidt.bugs.data"});

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        return builder
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
                .setName("database")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    private Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        return properties;
    }
}
```

**Test:**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={TestConfiguration.class})
@Transactional
@SpringBootTest
public class DataTest {

    @Autowired
    private DataRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void fail() {

        Data d = new Data();
        d.setData(new byte[255]);

        d = repository.save(d);
        repository.flush();

        d.setData(new byte[256]);
        repository.save(d);
        repository.flush();
    }

    @Test
    public void fail2() {

      Data d = new Data();
      d.setData(new byte[1025]);

      d = repository.save(d);
      repository.flush();

      d.setData(new byte[1026]);
      repository.save(d);
      repository.flush(); // <- fails here
    }

    @Test
    public void ok() {

        Data d = new Data();
        d.setData(new byte[254]);

        d = repository.save(d);
        repository.flush();

        d.setData(new byte[255]);
        repository.save(d);
        repository.flush();
    }
}
```

**The fail method is throwing:**

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:263)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:225)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.flush(Unknown Source)
    at de.ehscheidt.bugs.data.DataTest.fail(DataTest.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3217)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3090)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3491)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:600)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1437)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1423)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:304)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy42.flush(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.flush(SimpleJpaRepository.java:534)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:377)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:629)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:593)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLDataException: data exception: string data, right truncation
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: data exception: string data, right truncation
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.types.BlobType.convertToType(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.getUpdatedData(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.executeUpdateStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.getResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDMQL.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 78 more
```

**Important:** The exception is thrown at the second flush which results in an UPDATE.

**Used Libs:**

- spring-boot-starter-data-jpa: 2.0.2.RELEASE
- hibernate-core: 5.2.17.Final
- hsqldb: 2.4.0

I guess it has to do something with hibernate or/and hsqldb. Interesting is that hibernate generates the table as **'data blob(255)'**.

So, INSERT with more than 255 Bytes is ok, but UPDATE with more than it is not?

What am I missing?

Comment: As Paul said, the test didn't show a insert with more than 255 bytes. Now I have added a second failing test which shows inserting 1025 bytes. The later update with 1026 bytes will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is to do with using `byte[]` as the datatype.  It seems that once you have created a record with 255 (or 1025 or in fact any length of) characters that's all that you have available to use.  My guess is that HSQLDB treats byte[] LOBs as a primitive type and stores them inline in a variable length record.

If you use Java streams instead then HSQLDB will treat it as a proper variable length LOB.  [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/) uses streams underneath the covers so you wont hit this limitation.

It is super easy to modify your app to use it too:

Add the Spring Content dependencies to your pom.

> pom.xml

```
   <dependency
      <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-content-jpa-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.11</version>
   </dependency>
   <!-- and if you want the REST endpoints too -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-content-rest-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.11</version>
   </dependency>
```

Update your entity so that you can associate content.

> data.java

```
@Entity
public class Data {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private long id;

   @ContentId
   private String contentId;

   @ContentLength
   private long contentLength = 0L;

   // if you have rest endpoints
   @MimeType
   private String mimeType = "text/plain";

   ...
```

Define a ContentStore interface:

> DataContentStore.java

```
@StoreRestResource(path="dataContent")
public interface DataContentStore extends ContentStore<Data, String> {
}
```

And that's it.  At runtime Spring Content will manage the database schema for you.  It will inject a JPA implementation of `DataContentStore` that uses java streams rather than `byte[]`.  If you added the rest dependency it will also add a controller offering REST endpoints at '/dataContent'.

Over and above being able to insert larger LOBs over time, the other advantages of using Spring Content are:

- you don't have to write any of the code to do this yourself
- very large file handling (because it uses streams, not byte arrays)
- video streaming is support
- full text search is possible (Spring Content Solr)
- renditions in other formats are possible
- finally, you can easily switch your application to different
  storage with just one dependency change

There is a getting started guides that describes almost exactly what you are trying to do [here](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/spring-content-fs-docs/) and [here](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/spring-content-rest-docs/).  The reference guide for Spring Content JPA is [here](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/refs/release/jpa-index.html).

HTH

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for your hint regarding Spring Content. But I don't see it in my use case. Using SpringData here is only for easy setup. In my real project I only use Hibernate and JPA (EntityManager) on top of a HSQLDB.

Comment: You should probably change the title of this question to something like "HSQLDB fixes length of LOB fields upon insert" as this will make it easier for others to find this answer in future.

Comment: If you don't use Spring Content REST then there is no dependency on Spring Data.  It can be used on its own.